Ubuntu 24.04 does not finish booting > black screen
I have just installed Ubuntu 24.04 in dual boot with W11. It worked perfectly except that it won't start: black screen.
I've already looked for solutions.
I've tried to repair the packages and the grub in safe mode, without success.
The following command may help:
journalctl --no-pager -b -p err
sept. 07 16:27:16 AsusTourUbuntu24 (udev-worker)[479]: event7: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x7c, and key code 190: Invalid argument
sept. 07 16:27:16 AsusTourUbuntu24 kernel: 
sept. 07 16:27:17 AsusTourUbuntu24 bluetoothd[1174]: profiles/sap/server.c:sap_server_register() Sap driver initialization failed.
sept. 07 16:27:17 AsusTourUbuntu24 bluetoothd[1174]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
sept. 07 16:27:17 AsusTourUbuntu24 bluetoothd[1174]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
sept. 07 16:27:24 AsusTourUbuntu24 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
sept. 07 16:27:29 AsusTourUbuntu24 gdm-password][2293]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
sept. 07 16:27:32 AsusTourUbuntu24 systemd[2304]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dpkcs11-2672.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
sept. 07 16:27:32 AsusTourUbuntu24 systemd[2304]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dsecrets-2666.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
sept. 07 16:27:32 AsusTourUbuntu24 systemd[2304]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dssh-2669.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
sept. 07 16:27:33 AsusTourUbuntu24 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
sept. 07 16:27:33 AsusTourUbuntu24 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
sept. 07 16:27:33 AsusTourUbuntu24 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

I also tried changing the line in the /etc/default/grub file :
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

with
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nvidia-drm.modeset=1"

or
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"

without success.
I've also try to update grub, to purge nvidia package and reinstall them.
Currently, to start Ubuntu, a trick works: after booting on W11, the next Ubuntu startup works! Not very practical, but at least I can work on my computer. A direct reboot from Ubuntu also works, but never a reboot from a switched-off computer.
Before Ubuntu 24.04, I had Ubuntu 22.04, which worked very well alongside W11. I had tried an upgrade which didn't work, so I've just installed Ubuntu 24.04 instead of 22.04.
What's the problem? Nvidia driver problem? Configuration?
Thanks for your help.

You probably have a Windows issue. Many times Windows will take control of hardware and when you exit Windows it does not release it. Make sure that in Windows you do not have secure boot on, do not have bit locker in use and you have truly shutdown Windows completely before rebooting and trying to start Ubuntu. Make sure Windows is not hibernating or in any kind of stand by mode.

I've done all these tests. Before Ubuntu 24.04, I was on version 22.04 with no problems. I didn't change anything in W11 when I changed versions.

Where in the question does it say this was an upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04.? Any answer is only as good as the info supplied.

I tried an upgrade 22.04 -> 24.04, but it didn't work. So I installed Ubuntu 24.04 from scratch.
